# How to import a column from a sheet to another without pasting the top of the table?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to import a column from one sheet to another without pasting the top of the table.
  This is my code, can someone tell me how to fix it ?

```
Public Sub Click()
 Sheets("PTR").Range("B4").Select

 Worksheets("Analyse").Range("C:C").Copy Destination:=Sheets("PTR").Range("B:B")
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem with it? What happens?

Comment: when i click on the button it imports even the top( header) of the column.. but in the other sheet i have a new table with another tops ..i just wanna import the column from the first cell of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
Worksheets("Analyse").Range("C:C").Copy Destination:=Sheets("PTR").Range("B:B")
```

to

```
lRow = Worksheets("Analyse").Range("C2").end(xldown).row
Worksheets("Analyse").Range("C2:C" & lRow ).Copy Destination:=Sheets("PTR").Range("B2:B" & lRow)
```

This will copy to the end of the data not the whole column, so you may want to consider clearing "PTR" "B2:B" before this runs

Comment: If you want to take the whole column you can just switch to lRow = Worksheets("Analyse").rows.count

Comment: Thank u it works but i still have a ^problem ..the size of the columns isn't the same ..because i should copy from C6 and paste from B3..
Public Sub Click()
 Sheets("PTR").Range("B3").Select
 lRow = Worksheets("Analyse").Range("C6").End(xlDown).Row
 Worksheets("Analyse").Range("C6:C" & lRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("PTR").Range("B3:B" & lRow)
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub